How to create 3D stair in Anylogic 3D for ped change level?
In Example Anylogic have Ped Escalator from Pedestrain Library that can drag and drop .
In Example Anylogic have Ped walking up the stairs for 2D that use Ped Change level that use Rectangular Node with Position and size Slope for pedestrains option . But for 3D is not effect .
I need some guide to create 2D and 3D for Ped waling up the stairs .
How to create 3D stair and effect with 2d for let ped change level ?
